# i cant find why missing comma errors in mapper

Tags: spring, mapper

**Mapper Query:**

```
insert into w_carinfo values(car_number=#{car_number}, company=#{company}, 
        car_model=#{car_model}, color=#{color}, fuel=#{fuel}, gear=#{gear}, price=#{price}, 
        user_name=#{user_name}, location=#{location}, type=#{type}, driving=#{driving}, made_date=#{made_date})
```

**Error:**

```
org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.jdbc.BadSqlGrammarException: 
Error updating database.  Cause: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00917: missing comma

The error may involve mapper.myMapper.putCarInfo-Inline
The error occurred while setting parameters
SQL: insert into w_carinfo values(car_number=?, company=?, car_model=?, color=?, fuel=?, gear=?, price=?, user_name=?, location=?, type=?, driving=?, made_date=?)
Cause: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00917: missing comma

; bad SQL grammar []; nested exception is java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00917: missing comma

    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:948)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:838)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:660)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:812)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:88)
    org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
```

Comment: If possible please update this with code

Comment: i did solution that problem but thank you for reply me :D